# Angular select filter show all

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

Say i have the following `ng-repeat`

```
  <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="user in users | filter:search:strict">
```

For this i have a select that looks like this:

```
    <select class="form-control"
        ng-model="search.title.name"
        ng-options="item.name as item.name for item in titles">
    <option value="">Vælg jobprofil</option>
</select>
```

Now this works however when i choose the `Vælg jobprofil` option everything is removed because it searches for names that are like `""` so my question is how do add an `all` option to a select filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of keeping `All` as default option, keep it as a part of titles list and bind to a value property. Remove the value property for "All" option.

Example:-

```
$scope.titles = [{
    name: 'All'
  }, {
    name: 'A',
    value: 'A'
  }, {
    name: 'B',
    value: 'B'
  }, {
    name: 'C',
    value: 'C'
  }, {
    name: 'D',
    value: 'D'
  }];
```

and

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="search.title.name" ng-options="item.value as item.name for item in titles">
```

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.titles = [{
    name: 'All'
    
  }, {
    name: 'A',
    value: 'A'
  }, {
    name: 'B',
    value: 'B'
  }, {
    name: 'C',
    value: 'C'
  }, {
    name: 'D',
    value: 'D'
  }]
  $scope.users = [{
    name: 'Aasd'
  }, {
    name: 'Bsd'
  }, {
    name: 'Csd'
  }, {
    name: 'Dsd'
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <ul>
    <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="user in users | filter:search:strict">{{user.name}}</li>
  </ul>

  <select class="form-control" ng-model="search.name" ng-options="item.value as item.name for item in titles">
  </select>
</div>
```